# How to plot or draw custom designed charts in BIRT reports?

Tags: javascript, birt

I am trying to generate a report (with Charts and other lists) based on some data from a conventional scripted datasource. Basically, the charts that BIRT provides are not suitable for my report so I thought maybe I can produce some charts(with an external app) based on the data from database, saving the charts into files and eventually, dynamically load those files into my report. So here are my questions:

1. Is this possible to somehow create custom designed charts? if yes how
   to do this? and how can I add charts to the report?
2. I have all the data needed in dataset from scripted datasource, is it possible to draw graphics on 
   the fly with some javascript while the report is being created? I mean by using the data I just
   draw my own custom designed chart?(this is a very simple chart and no fancy stuff).

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at some different chart libraries. Fusion Charts (www.fusioncharts.com) have many more charts than standard BIRT does.  BIRT Designer Professional (the version of BIRT Designer that you pay for) provides access to Fusion Charts.

You can also check out Chart Da Vinci that is a programmatic interface to the BIRT Chart API that provides you with an easy to use technique (so they say) for building and customizing charts.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Chart Da Vinci. That might actually lead to a workable solution. I don't think the API will.

Answer (score 0):

BIRT has a chart API. Its documentation lives [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.chart.doc.isv%2Fchart%2Fapi%2Findex.html).

To answer both your questions: yes, you can, and yes, you can - the API has all the info, although it's not the most user friendly.